# Jenkins Build with Parameter and authentication but no parameter value

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-plugins

I have tried numerous ways to pass a URL automatically with authentication and a parameter (from build with parameters plugin) to start the job remote via the wget command:

```
/usr/bin/wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=<http-user> --http-password=<password like> http://<IP>:8080/job/<jobName>/buildWithParameters?token=<tokeName>&<param1>=<text1>
```

The non parameterized version runs smoothly without any issue but then the necessary `<param1>` is not available for the job.

Setting a default value for  in the build with pararmeters job, runs the job smoothly but defeats the purpose of running remotely through a script.

Here is a sanitized output:

```
Started by remote host x.x.x.x
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - The given properties file path '/var/lib/jenkins/<paramsFolder>/.properties' doesn't exist.
[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Missing file path was resolved from pattern '/var/lib/jenkins/<paramsFolder>/${NAMESTR}.properties' .
ERROR: SEVERE ERROR occurs
org.jenkinsci.lib.envinject.EnvInjectException: java.io.IOException: The given properties file path '/var/lib/jenkins/<paramsFolder>/.properties' doesn't exist.
```

In the configuration of the job, NAMESTR is defined as a String Parameter. When given the proper default value the job runs as expected. Without a default value in the job then the parameter value is not available through the wget command for the job as the output above shows.

I must have authentication and a command line means to supply the parameter to the job. I cannot interact with the Jenkins user interface to run the command manually.

Any thoughts? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the wget option --post data works for the BuildWithParameters plugin.

```
/usr/bin/wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=<http-user> --http-password=<password like> --post-data 'param1=text1' http://<IP>:8080/job/<job name>/buildWithParameters?token=<tokenName>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use `cURL`, it works for me like a dream.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/test_job/buildWithParameters?RandomUser=Tom --user admin:admin
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried a couple of options using curl but have not had success yet with the API token. Since the wget version above is working with API token, auth no challenge, and parameters (key value pairs) therefore  I don't have a driving need to make this work with curl also.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Http request plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin)

Select **Http Request** form **Add build step**

paste your url in **URL** field

Select **POST** method from **Http mode**

If you want to add authentication then update auth details in to your Jenkins **Configure Global Settings**.

Comment: The implementation needs to use a remote command like wget. This solution appears valid for setup and use on the Jenkins user interface.